# multirow grid using bootstrap without nested grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to make a multirow column for desktop, and for mobile the layout of the grid will be different. please see the images below.
[Desktop Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrgoC.png)
[Mobile Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOUZo.png). 
In mobile element B will be first. but for desktop A will be on the right side, spanning two rows. I tried doing this by rearranging the desktop layout using col-md-push-#/col-md-pull-#, but i cant make B and C in the same column/different row and make A span the two rows.
I know i can achieve the desktop layout using nested grids but i cant rearrange the elements using push-pull anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap 4—which has support for flexboxes—would be nice but here's one way you could possibly do it without nesting but you'd need to create some custom classes. Here's [a demo](http://codepen.io/allejo/pen/MaGjGa).

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="pull-sm-right col-sm-6">
    <p>B</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pull-sm-left col-sm-6">
    <p>A</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pull-sm-right col-sm-6">
    <p>C</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the custom classes you would need are the `.pull-*-<location>` classes as such:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .pull-sm-right {
    float: right !important;
  }

  .pull-sm-left {
    float: left !important;
  }
}
```

You would need to configure the heights of the `div`s manually but Bootstrap's float based grid system never really matched the heights of the columns.